# Java Read from serial (jserialcomm) one byte at a time

Tags: java, byte

I am new to Java. But I think I am trying a fairly complicated task.
I am trying to read from the serial port, with the jSerialComm class. I am managing to read something but I can't get it to read what I want.

Basically my need is to read a number which consists of 4 bytes. What I want then is if someone knows how to make Java read the 4 bytes (into a buffer I guess), then I can store or print that value, till I read my next 4 bytes.

Could someone suggest something? At the moment I am reading with something of the sort:

```
InputStream in = chosenPort.getInputStream();
(char)in.read()
```

I would really appreciate some help.
Elias

Comment: If you want to read 4 bytes, how many times you need to call `in.read()`? (Im sure you know how to store 4 bytes in an array)

Comment: The question is how do I make sure that the 4 bytes are the correct ones. In other words, the serial will keep sending them, but I need to make sure I always read them in the correct order. If I read 4 times in.read() in the next loop I might read bytes 2-3-4-1 instead of 1-2-3-4

Comment: Seems odd to me that byte order is an issue here. How could you possibly get any correct information if even on byte level, the data order is not consistent? Are you sure that its possible to get a mixedup result like that? (E.g. have you tested this, or is there any hint to this problem in the documentation?)

Comment: I have many different signals coming in. I have 2 sensors, and a logger sending data from those sensors to the serial port. I have to be able to read four digit number (such as 1.56 for instance) for each of them. So I have 8 bytes coming in representing those two numbers, one for each sensor. In matlab for instance we created an 8 byte buffer. the buffer is filled with the values (ASCII code) coming from the  serial. we then split 4 and 4 , convert to numbers and plot. This was the idea I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright that becomes more complicated, but still. If you cannot gurantee any order in incomming bytes there is no way to accomplish this. You need to be able to verify where a byte is comming from (how? By another byte?). So if you were able to create this mechanism with matlab, how did you verrify the source of each byte?

Comment: Ps. Since you work with hardware here, what does the hardware offer to solve this problem?